# Save DataSet to Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

I'm trying create a excel file based in a Dataset.

This is my really simple code.

```
 using (var dataSet = new DataSet())
            {
                var table = dataSet.Tables.Add("TotalUsers");
                table.Columns.Add("ProfileType");
                table.Columns.Add("March");
                table.Columns.Add("April");

                return this.Export("Excel", dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().AsQueryable(), "LoggedBlau");
```

but my excel file result in this:

```
RowError    RowState    Table   Item    Item    Item    Item    Item    Item    ItemArray   HasErrors
```

I have to pass  to Export a iqueryble. I think is there my mistake.

Comment: What is `this.Export`?

Comment: this.Export is a base method to download the files. CSV, Excel, my question is how can I pass my table as Iquerible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the actual properties defined in `DataRow`, not the columns of your table.

You need to change your `Export()` method to check for & consume `IListProvider` to get custom `PropertyDescriptor`s for the columns, or use classes with actual properties (eg, an anonymous type) instead of `DataTable`.